# Way to determine true calling assembly

Tags: c#, security

I have some security built into a client side program that downloads a DLL from the web, and called a function inside that DLL. The DLL is strong-named, and the function in the DLL uses `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` to determine the calling assembly so that I can accurately get a path to the program who called it.  From there we do a hash check of the assembly and verify that it is the correct one.

We have people that have gotten themselves attached in full trust mode, and are able to spoof the `GetCallingAssembly` call to point to the real executable, while they run a modified version of it. Is there something else other then `GetCallingAssembly` that I can use to get the true caller?  Some callstack or something that may provide the real executable since `GetCallingAssembly` seems to be easily spoofed.

Comment: Try the `GetEntryAssembly` method instead

Comment: Mind you, if you allow full trust, they can also patch GetEntryAssembly. If you allow full trust, they can also patch your downloaded DLL and disable the hash check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this while running in full trust mode.  Full trust means people can do things like spoofing.  Here is a similar discusison:
[reflection is possible on obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769226/reflection-is-possible-on-obfuscation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how secure it is, but I've used this in the past to get the startup path:

```
string startup_path =
   Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SomeClassInDll).Assembly.Location);
```

Comment: I think this person is using some kind of tool which is changing the CallingAssembly, If they disable the hash we detect it, it phones home to the server with a hash which is generated from inside of the dll, the dll changes some secret keys inside which will change the response, it hashed that secret key, plus the hash of the assembly to determine if it is modified and that they are using the proper hash assembly. Im trying to find some methods that i can look at that might be a bit harder to spoof. Like the call stack maybe?